# Why does EEVEE not have a displacement option?

Tags: rendering

When I switch in to EEVEE there is no micro displacement in the options.

Why won't micro displacement work in EEVEE?

Comment: Someone asked this question on https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ane79b/micro_displacements_question and got an answer

Answer (score 2):

Because no one has coded it for Eevee yet. Eevee can't use any of Cycles' displacement system. For best performance at least, it would need a completely new displacement engine based around OpenGL tessellation shaders. No one has gotten around to writing this yet, so for now Eevee just applies displacement nodes as a bump map.